# I want to delete first characters in a cell?

Tags: excel

I want to delete first characters in a cell and show it in another cell.

I have  A1 - `1900: (1873, 'asd@asd.com`

I want to show B1 - `asd@asd.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RIGHT` function to 'keep' a number of characters:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-B1)
```

Will chop off B1 characters of the content of cell A1  (in this case, B1 should contain 14, but you can make it a calculation, too)

Answer (score 1):

If you have always a quote before your email, just select you column, go to Data / convert and use "'" as separator

Answer (score 0):

If the apostrophe precede every e-mail address then this formula can be used in column B.

=MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,LEN(A1))

The find function returns the first occurrence of the apostrophe.
The Mid function extracts the text after the apostrophe.